# How to display DateTime in "yyyy/MM/dd" Format sfDatagrid for UWP

Tags: uwp-xaml, syncfusion

I am using sfDataGrid in my UWP app and in one column I want to display datetime in "yyyy/MM/dd" string format, I have used both GridTextColumn and GridDateTimeColumn but no luck. There is a FormatString property in GridDateTimeColumn but setting that also not making any difference.

[image]

Comment: use 
StringFormat='{}{0:yyyy/MM/dd}'
note can also use string formatters like
StringFormat='short date'
or
StringFormat='d'

Comment: Note the set of brackets is important if setting in xaml

Answer (score 0):

Can use

```
                                    <syncfusion:GridDateTimeColumn MappingName="QuestionName"
                                                           ColumnSizer="Star"
                                                           AllowSorting="True"
                                                               AllowFiltering="True"
                                                               DateTimeFormat='{}{0:yyyy/MM/dd}' />
```

Your column data from view model must be of type Datatime and not just a string to use the DateTimeFormat. Else just use a string based column coontrol and the same code in binding.

Comment: no property called 'DateTimeFormat' in sfDataGrid of UWP.

Answer (score 0):

In case, the default patterns do not meet your requirements, you can customize the date and time format by setting CustomPattern.

An example for custom format is displayed in the following code sample for WPF.

```
<syncfusion:SfDataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"                                                                       
                   AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                   ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}">
<syncfusion:SfDataGrid.Columns>
    <syncfusion:GridDateTimeColumn  CustomPattern="dd-m-yyyy hh:mm:ss"
                                    HeaderText="Order Date"
                                    MappingName="OrderDate"
                                    Pattern="CustomPattern" />
</syncfusion:SfDataGrid.Columns>
```

for UWP

```
<syncfusion:GridDateTimeColumn FormatString="yyyy/dd/MM"
                           HeaderText="Order Date"
                           MappingName="OrderDate"
                           SelectorFormatString="yyyy/dd/MM" />
```

More detail is here WPF https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/sfdatagrid/column-types#change-the-pattern-of-date-time-value

UWP https://help.syncfusion.com/uwp/sfdatagrid/column-types#griddatetimecolumn

Comment: @Rahul, Did you get help from this answer?